# Custom ProgressBar in Android using PNG

Tags: android, xml

How do I create a custom progressbar in Android that has a drawable for the progress and background items?

All examples I saw were gradients, like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#000001"
                    android:centerColor="#0b131e"
                    android:centerY="1.0"
                    android:endColor="#0d1522"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>

 <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#007A00"
                    android:centerColor="#007A00"
                    android:centerY="1.0"
                    android:endColor="#06101d"
                    android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Instead of gradient, I want to use an image, a png or a drawable.

Comment: Considering that a `ProgressBar` can be of any arbitrary size in pixels (based on screen size and density), using "an image, a png or a drawable" may not give you quality results. That being said, try `<bitmap>` in place of `<shape>`.

Comment: Try this. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-transparent-progress-dialog-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like that

```
        ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, null, null, true, false);

        pd.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);

        ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) pd.findViewById(R.id.pdWithImage);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.default_profile_image);
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b);

        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

and this is the custom progressbar layout

progressdialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<ProgressBar
   android:id="@+id/pdWithImage"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add progressbar_progress_clip.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_progressing"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left"/>
```

Then, add the progress bar and two images in a relative layout, so that the images can be drawn after the status bar. Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_weight="94" >

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/pBarOverallStatus"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
                    android:max="100"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_progress_clip" >
                </ProgressBar>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ringLeft"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/status_bar_ring"
                    android:src="@drawable/status_bar_ring" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ringRight"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/status_bar_ring"
                    android:src="@drawable/status_bar_ring" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```